# Как сделать inlinebutton с ссылкой pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалась ссылка?
Так не работает
Module - pyrogram

```
app2 = Client(
    'bot',
    api_id=api_id,
    api_hash=api_hash,
    bot_token=bot_token
)

@app2.on_message(Filters.regex('http'))
def time(client, message):
    url = message.text
    text = settings.parsing(url)
    client.send_message(
        'chat_id',
        text[0],
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[
            InlineKeyboardButton('Смотреть онлайн!', url=text[1], callback_data='watch online'),
            InlineKeyboardButton('Поиск фильмов!', url='http://f1.ikino.site/index.php?do=search',
                                 callback_data='search films',)
        ]]),
    )


app2.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать библиотеку webbrowser и лямбду

```
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```